# Can I verify the transaction information of in-app billing with the Android Market server directly?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

If I have the transaction information json string:

```
{ "nonce" : 1836535032137741465,
  "orders" :
  { "notificationId" : "android.test.purchased",
    "orderId" : "transactionId.android.test.purchased",
    "packageName" : "com.example.dungeons",
    "productId" : "android.test.purchased",
    "developerPayload" : "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ",
    "purchaseTime" : 1290114783411,
    "purchaseState" : 0
  }
}
```

can i just upload it to Android Market server to verify if it is valid.
Just like the Apple way.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html

**Update:**
I am updating this to get some info about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

In android we can't verify the transaction information of in-app billing with the Android Market server directly.
And I thinks there is not need to verify the transaction because it's very secure.(Nothing like jailbreak in android) :).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you cannot communicate with android market.Check this link that has other issues as well

[this](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?fid=5e70c3851f628fa20004b0e6d9f08cae&hl=en)

Update :

Now you can verify subscription with new versions of Android Play.Check [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/v2/billing_subscriptions.html). 
This needs OAuth since you are requesting permission to access information from Google. However the process is well documented and you can follow it yourself.